# NodeJS twitter-ads lib cannot find my account (Account <myaccountnumber> was not found)

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth-2.0, ads-api

So when I use twurl ...

```
twurl -H "https://ads-api.twitter.com" "/2/accounts/<myaccountnumber>"
```

I get the correct response back with all the information about said ads account. This, i assume, means i'm good to go on all account authorization/whitelisting on twitter's side of things. yes? That my ads account and my app are tied together properly?

When I run the code example on https://github.com/FallenTech/twitter-ads

```
var TwitterAdsAPI = require('twitter-ads');
var T = new TwitterAdsAPI({
  consumer_key: 'XXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token: 'XXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXX'
});

T.get('accounts/:account_id', {account_id: 'XXX'}, function(error, resp, body) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(body);

});
```

I get

```
{ code: 'NOT_FOUND',
   message: 'Account <myaccountnumber> was not found' }
```

What step am I missing here? When i authorized twurl i only used consumer-key and consumer-secret.

I have also tried...

```
T.get('accounts/:account_id', {account_id: 'XXX', sandbox: false, api_version: '2'}, function(error, resp, body) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the flags `sandbox: false` and `api_version: '2'` in your TwitterAdsAPI configuration, and not as part of the object of your second argument in your `T.get` function as you specified you did in your code snippet. See example below:

```
var TwitterAdsAPI = require('twitter-ads');
var T = new TwitterAdsAPI({
  consumer_key: 'XXX',
  consumer_secret: 'XXX',
  access_token: 'XXX',
  access_token_secret: 'XXX',
  sandbox: false,
  api_version: '2'
});

T.get('accounts/:account_id', {account_id: 'XXX'}, function(error, resp, body) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(body);

});
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!